# Dependent data validation rule in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have a cell that has two dropdown choices Variable or Fixed. I am trying to allow the next cell over to all the user to enter any number when Variable is chosen but only allow users to enter 1 when fixed is chosen or else they receive a data validation message.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Suppose cell B2 = Fixed or Variable, and you are trying to establish the validation on the adjacent cell C2.

Add the below custom validation for C2. This will only allow C2 to be set to 1 if B2 is "Fixed", or, allow C2 to be greater that 0 if B2 is "Variable". You can adjust the second AND condition to allow any permissible values in C2 that you need to:

> =OR(AND(B2="Fixed",C2=1),AND(B2="Variable",C2>0))

Screenshot for custom validation settings form as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative (better) solution.

It allows any number to be entered when `Variable` is selected, and, more importantly, it will stop users from bypassing the validation by entering a number in the adjacent cell *before* choosing an option from the dropdown.

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following as the custom data validation formula  for `B2`:

```dart
=(A2="")*(B2="")+(A2="Fixed")*(B2=1)+(A2="Variable")*ISNUMBER(B2)
```

Make sure that `Ignore blank` is left unchecked.

**Caveats:**

Unfortunately, this is the best that can be achieved with just data validation. Users can still bypass the validation by:

- Selecting `Variable`, entering a number other than one in the adjacent cell, and then selecting `Fixed`
- Pasting any value into the cell
- Filling down into the cell
- Ctrl-entering any value in a selected range if the adjacent cell is a part of, but not the active cell of, the range.

The *only* way to do "foolproof" validation is by using VBA.

However, there is one more thing that can be done without using VBA. A helper cell or conditional formatting can be used to alert the user that the data is invalid, and then trust that they will fix the issue.